# Power BI - Filter all visuals by different time periods and a pre filtered month or date

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, dax

Task to Perform: Filter all visuals with different time periods (eg Rolling last 12 Months), with a pre filtered year month or date filter (eg if April 2020 is selected it should show the visuals filtered from April 2019 to April 2020). If nothing is selected in the date filter and the period has selected Rolling last 12 Months, it should show from August 2021 to August 2022.

In short, the period filter should be able to be filtered by a dynamic date/month...

[image]

I have to related tables, one with the Date dimension and the other one with the Periods I created and want to be able to filter, and I have them as a filter in my visuals (it works fine for the current date):

[image]

But of course if I filter a month from the table Date, the Period does not go beyond that selected in the table Date (eg if August 2020 is selected, Rolling last 12M only shows August 2020)

Could anyone please tell me how to get the above requirement?

Comment: What is your slicer made of?

Comment: I'm using the field "Bookmark Desc" from the table "D Periods", it's related with "D Date" by the field "Date". The idea would be to have another slicer from the table "D Date" (eg Year/Month) and be able to filter by August 2021, and have the "D Period" filter dynamically change the selected range to the new filtered date (Eg rolling last 12 Month should change from August 2021 - August 2022 to August 2020 - August 2021)

Comment: I think It' would be better if you add the pbix file /dummy